# function return pending promise instead of result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to use this function to check if a user is authorized to access a ressource:

```
const Authorisation = require('../models/Authorisation');

const isAuthorized = async (role, employee, objectId) => {
  const myAuth = await Authorisation.find({ employee: employee.id })
    .populate('auth')
    .then(auth => {
      return auth
        .filter(authItem => role.includes(authItem.auth.name))
        .filter(
          authItem =>
            authItem.organisationtype[0].item.toString() === objectId.toString()
        );
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err;
    });

  return myAuth;
};
module.exports = isAuthorized;
```

If I use `console.log(myAuth)` inside the function just before returning it, I get the result, but when I call the function, I get a pending promise instead of a result.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isAuthorized` is itself an async function and will always return a Promise. So if you call `isAuthorized`, have to wait for the result to be resolved:

```
var auth = await isAuthorized()
```

Or

```
isAuthorized().then( auth => ... })
```

As soon as one parte of the code returns data in an asynchronous way everything else that depends on it has to has to by asynchronous too. No matter if it is `Promise`/`async`,  `callbacks`, ..